# Lookahead assertions and grouping with python regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

Say I have many lines of text, such as this one:

```
row = '   S.G. Primary School\t\t 434,612.50'
```

And I want to find a number that looks like it is formatted the way accountants do, then I want to look backwards and pull the word or words preceeding that number. I have this for the number:

```
test = re.search(r"""(?=((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$))""",row)
   S.G. Primary School       434,612.50
test.groups()
('434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
```

Which looks correct. I have the full number and the parts of it (all of which I want). But I cannot figure out how to get the word (or phrase) before the number with a look ahead assertion.

I tried:

```
test = re.search(r"""([A-Za-z ].*) (?=((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$))""",row)
('   S.G. Primary School\t\t', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
```

I spent 4 hours this week rereading regex docs and I still don't know if I am getting anywhere. Examples don't seem to work for me. I cannot use \w+ because I want the labels to be only text and spaces, but I also want to start counting backwards from the start of a matching number. That sounds like a "positive lookahead assertion" with the general format of "\w+(?=\d)" but that doesn't work for me.

Also - I am confused about the proper way to assign MULTIPLE lookahead assertions that ALL need to be true before the match returns:

is

```
r"""([A-Za-z ]*)(.*?)([\d,.]+)(?=[A-Za-z ]*)(?=[\d,.])"""
```

any different from

```
r"""([A-Za-z ]*)(?=[A-Za-z ]*)(.*?)([\d,.]+)(?=[\d,.])"""
```

because both yield the same result in this example:

```
('   S', '.G. Primary School\t\t ', '434,612.5')
```

**UPDATE**

Here are three examples for which I am stuggling to find a regex answer:

```
import re
rows = ['   S.G. Primary School\t\t 434,612.50',
       '   S.G. Bad Primary School\t\t 434,612.50',
       '   N.3#=42^2492q\t\t\t 434,612.50']

for row in rows:
    test = re.search(r"""(?!\s)([A-Za-z]{0,25}) ?([a-zA-Z]{6,25}).*?(?=(?:(?:-?\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$))((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$)""",row)
    if test != None:
        print test.groups()
    else:
        print test
```

This returns:

```
('Primary', 'School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('Bad', 'Primary', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
None
```

I would like the result to be:

```
('Primary', 'School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('Primary', 'School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
```

And I would like the code to be adjustable so that I could also return:

```
('School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
```

with modifications.

**UPDATE**

Based on Casimir's answer, this returns better data but I do not understand how how get multiple word phrases preceeding the number:

```
test = re.search(r'([A-Za-z][A-Za-z_.]*){1,2}\s+((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$)',row)
('School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('q', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
```

and I don't know why

```
test = re.search(r'([A-Za-z_.]*){1,2}\s+((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$)',row)
```

Gives an error: nothing to repeat. All I've done is change

```
[A-Za-z][A-Za-z_.]*){1,2}
```

to

```
[A-Za-z_.]*){1,2}
```

in the first group.

Perhaps:

```
test = re.search(r'([A-Za-z][A-Za-z_.]*){0,}\s+([A-Za-z][A-Za-z_.]*){0,}\s+((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$)',row)
```

is better, because I get the first word and the second word back, but not sure how I can combine them and make them optional:

```
('Primary', 'School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('Primary', 'School', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
('q', None, '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')
```

**UPDATE**

I've taken Casimir's answer (slightly modified) {0,2} changed to {0,1} and tested it with a findall version:

```
import re
rows = ['   S.G. Primary School\t\t 434,612.50 S.G. Primary School\t\t 434,612.50',
       '   S.G. Bad Primary School\t\t 434,612.50 Bad Primary School\t\t 434,612.50',
       '   N.3#=42^2492q\t\t\t 434,612.50  N.3#=42^2492q\t\t\t 434,612.50  N.3#=42^2492q\t\t\t 434,612.50 ']

for row in rows:
    test = re.findall(r"(?i)([a-z][a-z_.]*(?:\s+[a-z][a-z_.]*){0,1})?\s+((-?\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$)",row)
    test = re.findall(r"(?i)([a-z][a-z_.]*(?:\s+[a-z][a-z_.]*){0,1})?\s+(-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?)",row)
    print test
```

But the first test returns this (when second test statement is commented out):

```
[('Primary School', '434,612.50', '434')]
[('Primary School', '434,612.50', '434')]
[]
```

And the second test statement returns this, a list of results - what I want, sorta:

```
[('Primary School', '434,612.50'), ('Primary School', '434,612.50')]
[('Primary School', '434,612.50'), ('Primary School', '434,612.50')]
[('q', '434,612.50'), ('q', '434,612.50'), ('q', '434,612.50')]
```

But the statements are so similar, I don't know why one is missing the multiple numbers / labels in the list.

Comment: I am a little confused. Isn't `('   S.G. Primary School\t\t', '434,612.50', '434', ',612', '.50')` what you are looking for?

Comment: Ideally, I want to understand this well enough to grab either ('Primary School', '434,612.50', '434, '612', '.50') or ('School', '434,612.50', '434, '612', '.50'). This will get me close but not "school" by itself: test = re.search(r"""(?!\s)([a-zA-Z ]{6,25}).*?(?=(?:(?:-?\d{1,3})(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$))((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$)""",row)

Comment: So you want to match `S.G. Primary School` without consuming the rest of the line but with checking for it to look like something specific (accountant's number), right?

Comment: This would capture the first "phrase" as is: `re.search(r"""(\s+\D+\s+(?=((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$)))""",row).groups()`. Is this what you are after?

Comment: @MarcMaxson: Why 'Primary School' and not 'S.G. Primary School'?

Comment: Yes- I want to return 1 or 2 words that are followed by a number that is formatted with , and . in the proper way typical for accounting documents. So would it be best to double lookahead (1: that the word is a word) and (2: that the number is a number following the word)?

Comment: I want to know how to return an arbitrary number of words (1,2,3...) starting the counting of the words from the number and looking backwards. S.G. would be the third "word" by this criteria and thus ignored if I am only fetching the 1st or 2nd word.

Comment: I still don't understand completely.  Maybe you can give a full example of an input and an output as you wish it.  A lookahead only makes sense if the unconsumed part is meant to be consumed later.  Otherwise it can simply be consumed on first match.  Please include that aspect in your example.

Comment: @Alfe added a longer example with 3 input strings and 2 desired output strings.

Comment: Okay, since you always seem to be allowed to consume the parts after what you want to return, you really don't seem to need a lookahead (no `(?=` necessary).  Just stick to specifying all you want and then draw from the match the parts you need and ignore the parts you don't need (what you had in your lookahead).

Comment: will this same pattern work with a findall() as it would for a search()? I imagine sorting through giant strings and returning ALL pairs of numbers and adjacent preceeding phrases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need lookahead at all:

```
(?i)([a-z][a-z_.]*(?:\s+[a-z][a-z_.]*){0,2})?\s+(-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?)
```

With `{0,...}` you can control how many words you want. If you want all the words, replace it by `*`. If you want one word max, you must remove all the non-capturing group:

```
(?i)([a-z][a-z_.]*)?\s+(-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?)
```

if you want exactly 3 words:

```
(?i)([a-z][a-z_.]*(?:\s+[a-z][a-z_.]*){2})\s+(-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?)
```

If you want to avoid single letters from "a non word" (like the "q" letter) you can add:

```
(?i)((?:^|(?<=\s))[a-z][a-z_.]*(?:\s+[a-z][a-z_.]*){0,2})?\s+(-?\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d\d)?)
```

pattern details:

```
(?i)                      # make the pattern case insensitive
(                         # open the first capturing group
    (?:^|(?<=\s))         # begining of the string or lookbehind with space
    [a-z][a-z_.]*         # a letter and zero or more chars from [a-z_.]
    (?:                   # open a non-capturing group
        \s+               # one or more spaces
        [a-z][a-z_.]*     # a letter and zero or more chars from [a-z_.]
    ){0,2}                # repeat the capturing group zero or two times
)?                        # close the capturing group and make it optional
\s+                       # one or more spaces
(                         # open a capturing group
    -?                    # - sign optional
    \d{1,3}               # between 1 or 3 digits
    (?:,\d{3})*           # a group (zero or more times) with a , and 3 digits
    (?:\.\d\d)?           # an optional group with a . and 2 digits
)                         # close the second capturing group.
```

Comment: We don't know that yet ;-)  He does not explain the complete case.

Comment: Yes, but I can feel throught the net in his spirit that he doesn't need a lookahead.

Comment: I tend to agree on that ;-)  But assumptions are the road to hell.

Comment: With your answer, I've found this to get closer (returns 'school' but not yet returns the 2-word version 'Primary School'):  

    r'([A-Za-z][A-Za-z_.]*){1,2}\s+((-?\d{1,3})(,\d{3})*(\.\d\d)?$|^\.\d\d$)'

Comment: @MarcMaxson: this is not my pattern.

Comment: Yes. I modified it. Your answer returned this:
('S.G. Primary School', '434,612.50')
('Bad Primary School', '434,612.50')
('q', '434,612.50')

Comment: I tried your second example starting with (?i)((?<=^|\s)[a-z][a-z_.]* and python replies: **"error: look-behind requires fixed-width pattern"** -- so is (?<=^|\s) allowed?

Comment: Thanks. With your edits this gives me enough of a framework/understanding to iterate on the text & number patterns to cover a wide variety of documents. Note that {0,1} repeats gives me the 'primary school' in this example that I wanted.